# Name of a "factorial" distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is there a common name for the distribution $P(m)=\frac{(m-1)}{m!}$, for integers $m\in \{1,\infty\}$? Its mean is $e$.

Comment: The domain of positive support is $m \in \{2, 3, 4, ...\}$.